# WordPress Comments are automatically publishing

Tags: comments, publish, draft

I want to manually approve comments when someone will comment on any of the post.
Right now when someone comment on any of the post these are automatically approved and published.
I have changed settings in Discussion for comments but still these are automatically approved may be because the author of comment is admin.
But i want to manually approve comments for all users whether admin or subscriber.
Is there any way to do this.
I will appreciate your guidance. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An administrator is normal the highest level of user in Wordpress. If you want to approve every comments, even administrator comments, maybe you can use the moderation filter.

If you go to `Settings` > `Discussion Settings` > `Comment Moderation`. You could setup an "cache all" filter. If you put all letters of the alphabet and the numbers 0 to 9 in as an filter, every comment should be send to the "moderation queue" for your approval.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a good idea but for my website this is not working. I have test this on other websites and it was working.